# Google Code Prettify for shell commands?

Tags: regex, shell, google-code-prettify

Is there any existing language to highlight shell syntax properly?

#### examples

```
$ sudo apt-get install foo      # this installs foo
```

#### expected output

> **$** sudo apt-get install foo      *# this installs foo*

---

My very simple approach to *fix* this - as you will see my regex skills are limited. Therefore my actual question is **is there any existing language** for shell highlighting?
Unfortunately there is no real documentation but the actual code.

```
# lang-shell.js
PR.registerLangHandler(PR.createSimpleLexer(
 [[PR.PR_PLAIN, /^[\t\n\r \xA0]+/, null, "\t\n\r \xA0"]],
 [[PR.PR_KEYWORD, /[$]/, null]]
), ["shell"]);
```

this works - it highlights every **$**

But when I add `..., [[PR.PR_COMMENT,/\#.*/]], ...` it only highlights the comments.

When I remove the nested array (since this is how the most other languages seems to work)

```
PR.registerLangHandler(PR.createSimpleLexer([
    [PR.PR_PLAIN, /^[\t\n\r \xA0]+/, null, "\t\n\r \xA0"],
    [PR.PR_COMMENT, /\#.*/],
    [PR.PR_KEYWORD, /\$/, null]
]), ["shell"]);
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined prettify.js:1
>   (anonymous function) prettify.js:1
>   f prettify.js:1
>   (anonymous function)

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Is there any (non-official) existing language (for google-code-prettify) to highlight shell syntax properly? (feel free to give me a hint to my attempt)

Comment: no sure what you mean. but you can use python's pygmentize. `pip install pygmentize; pygmentize -O style=monokai -f console256 -g file.sh`

Comment: @PeteyT that was not my question

Comment: @Brettetete You are asking for a language or regular expression(s) for highlighting for output similar to Google Code Prettify, are you not? So the premise is that you're trying to match some criteria to highlight output in your shell - why I flagged it as a possible duplicate because the base of your question is something that someone has already asked. If multiple people don't understand your question or what you are truly asking, edit your question to *clarify*, please. And also make your comments constructive as well.

Comment: @Signus I've asked for a google-code-prettify language. `Is there any (non-official) existing language (for google-code-prettify) to highlight shell syntax properly?`

Comment: @Brettetete A language - most certainly not (I think this is where the confusion is stemming from). However a shell script/configuration for terminal output may already exist. But really what you wanna look at is looking for or writing a vim syntax highlighting scheme. There are already hundreds of these for JavaScript files in vim. If you're looking at shell output more than you are vim, you may honestly have to write your own. Be sure to check out http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: @Brettetete That is not the case, the basis of your question is what many people here have asked. I understand Google Code Prettify, but what you *can* do is replicate the coloring that Google Code Prettify does. But what you have not answered is whether you're trying to merely display the code in a similar format while you're using `vim` or actually trying to **run** the code and display its output via the shell. Because you won't be able to use a JavaScript file to do this in the shell. You'd be using something like `remark`.

Comment: @Signus A google-code-prettify language is a javascript file that allows highlighting syntax. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/#svn%2Floader%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Comment: Yes, I know what it is. But you're trying to essentially reinvent the wheel. Syntax highlighting in vim - already been done. Shell highlighting in the terminal - already been done. You're not going to be running JavaScript in the shell to get syntax highlighting. The answer to your question has been "**Yes**, there already exists ways to do shell highlighting. However, **NO** you won't be using any variant of Google-Code-Prettify to do this, but you can *imitate* it."